# How to disable automatic capitalization in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice Calc Version 5.2.7.2.

I have everything I can find under Tools -> AutoCorrect turned off.

However, I still see capitalizations in certain cases.

Is there anything more I need to turn off to completely disable it?

It seems to be related to hyphens. Some strings with hyphens separating words such as this in a cell "foo -- bar -- baz" will capitalize bar to Bar. However, similar sentences, in a new cell, will not experience this behavior.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the capitalization you see?  Calc doesn't do much in terms of grammar and similar language correction.  Your description would include things like capitalization of the letters in function names.

Comment: I also encounter this problem. If I enter test in a cell, it doesn't capitalize, but if I enter test-me, it will capitalize the t. Hyphens seem to trigger this behaviour. Even without hitting enter, if you type a word with a hyphen then hit space, it will capitalize the hyphenated word if its the first word.

Comment: @dennisbjell I also get this behavior from hyphens. I didn't realize at first what caused it, but your comment made me realize what it was that actually did it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Deactivate the following option:

> Tools > AutoCorrect Options... > Options > Capitalize first letter of every sentence

[image: LibreOffice Calc: Capitalize first letter of every sentence]

It seems that it doesn't typically trigger (i.e., I can put a cell that contains `table`, or another one that contains `this is a message` and nothing autocorrects). But under certain circumstances, it is indeed triggered (e.g. when you put `this-notasentence`, `t` is capitalized). I am not sure why LibreOffice decides that having a hyphen means that it is a sentence and thus should be triggered.

It seems a misbehaviour of LibreOffice, or a bad heuristic. I am not sure if that's your specific case, but for sure it is what was happening to me, @dennisjbell and @AlphaCentauri.

---

@m93a comments may be relevant: If you are using LibreOffice version >=7, menus may be moved, and you can access the traditional ones by

> ⚙️>User Interface and change to Standard Toolbar

And change back by:

> View>User Interface>Tabbed

Comment: I don't see „AutoCorrect Options“ anywhere in Tools. This is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/Ah6ihxb.png

Comment: @m93a you have a fancy menu which doesn't resemble mine at all. Are you really using LibreOffice Calc? Can't you access the old-fashioned text menu? Sorry, no idea what I am looking at. I am using LibreOffice 6.4.6.2 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I had to go to ⚙️>User Interface and change to Standard Toolbar, then I could access the same menu you're reffering to. After that, I changed back to View>User Interface>Tabbed. I'm on LibreOffice 7.0.2.2 (from Flathub). The new Tabbed interface probably doesn't contain all the new functionality then. Good thing I can change back to the legacy UI.

Comment: Good to know! Added that to the answer for potential future readers

Comment: This is the answer. I have allowed myself to add a screenshot of the dialog in question.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer What is the full click path from the "just launched localc" state to the configuration dialog in the screenshot?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski    In LibreOffice 7.3.7 (Fedora 36), it is Menu:Tools > MenuEntry:AutoCorrect > SubMenu:"AutoCorrect Options" > Dialog Opens > Tab:Options, but then you get a different dialog than the one I added, then you find "Capitalize first letter of every sentence" with a tickmark for "M = Replace while modifying" or "T = AutoCorrect while typing". The bad idea of "deep menus" in 2024 is apparent, it would be nice if there were some kind of URI to a menu entry, someone should propose that